# For which $n$ does $\mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$ have the $n$-balancing property?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

> Let $A$ be an abelian group. We say $A$ has the *$n$-balancing property* if the following statement is true for $A$:
>
> "**Let $x_1, \cdots, x_{2n+1} \in A$ be any $2n+1$ elements. Suppose that for any $1\le i \le 2n+1$, the $2n$ elements $\{x_1, \cdots, x_{2n+1}\} \setminus \{x_i\}$ can be split into two size $n$ parts with equal sum. Then $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{2n+1}$.**"

The [AMM problem 11002](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4145115) is a classic puzzle, to show $\mathbb{R}$ has the $n$-balancing property for all $n\ge 1$. Related is the [Putnam 1973 B1](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol737.html), which is to show $\mathbb{Z}$ has the $n$-balancing property for all $n\ge 1$.

In [this AMM article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322479), Martin shows that an abelian group $A$ has the $n$-balancing property for all $n\ge 1$ iff $A$ has no nontrivial elements of odd order.

I am interested in the case when $A$ does contain nontrivial elements of odd order: for which $n$ does $A$ still satisfy the $n$-balancing property? By Corollary 5 in Martin's article, it suffices to consider this question for $A = \mathbb{Z}/p^k \mathbb{Z}$.

For example, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ does **not** satisfy the $n$-balancing property for $n=p$, since we could take $x_1 = \cdots = x_p = 0$ and $x_{p+1} = \cdots = x_{2p+1} = 1$.

Comment: The same example that you gave (except with more zeroes) shows that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ does not satisfy the $n$-balancing property for $n \geq p$, when $p$ is odd. So I would expect some condition like "$n$ small enough". Perhaps small enough to ensure that certain determinants don't vanish?

Comment: And the same holds for $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ if $n\geq p^k$. You can choose $p^k+1$ values $1$ and $2n-p^k$ zeros.

Comment: Also, if $B$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $B$ is does not have the $n$-balancing property, then $A$ does not. For example, if $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ and $n\geq p$ you can choose $p+1$ values of $p^{k-1}$ and $2n-p$ zeros.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307987/the-soccer-splitting-problem-in-arbitrary-commutative-ring